# Overheating and lags after watching movie/video

Tags: 17.10, overheating

My device is acer aspire v3-471g with a NVIDIA GeForce 630M 2GB Dedicated VRAM

Could someone help me with this issue? Because I really need to know what I need to do/install. I've been searching for the solution and installed thermald.
I've already installed NVIDIA driver too.

Comment: Depends on what software you are using for playing videos and video codecs. Maybe the videos use some codecs that aren't hardware accelerated.

Comment: I play it with ubuntu videos. should I use another player like vlc? or what is your suggestion? @SurvivalMachine

Comment: The "Nvidia X Server Settings" program shows the temp of the GPU, what does it show?  A laptop cooling platform/fan might be a good idea.